# how to determine significance with permutation t-distribution values

Tags: python, permutation-test

suppose I have the following array of t-distribution values from a permutation test (e.g., linear model which tests, for example, the influence of an adhd score and alcohol consumption on a stress (high stress =1, low stress=0) group label.

With python statsmodels, it looks like this:

```
formul = 'stress ~ alcohol'
model = sm.formula.logit(formula=str(formul),data=X).fit()
```

Now for display, let's say I did 10 rounds of a permutation test: I permute the dependend group variable and observe how the t value of predictor variable alcohol changes:

```
v =[1.894426,
0.524923
1.090838
0.334649
0.734943
0.076549
0.261809
0.692914
0.780390
1.031483]
```

these are t-distribution values from the permuted linear model.

then I have an empirical t-value from the unpermuted linear model, this is simply, the logit model without permutations;

```
v_unpermuted = 0.01
```

Now, I want to use the empirical t-value as "cut-off", as I want to test if the empirical value (v_unpermuted) in face of the permuted values is supporting the null hypothesis or not (null hypothesis: there is no association between the group label and alcohol consumption").

What I have so far:

```
cutoff_value = stats.t.ppf(q=1-.05/2,df=9)

v_r > cutoff_value
False
```

... can someone give me a hint how to find the significance when I have a bunch of permutation values and one empirical value, within a 95% confidence interval?

That would be awesome, I'm very thankful for any advice!

Edit: added further details

Comment: The answer depends on both your null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis.  I'm afraid the description "t-distribution values from the permuted linear model" gives us no indication of either of them (and scarcely helps us understand what your list of numbers might represent).  Please clarify this in your post.

Comment: I added the information in the posting

Comment: The t-values are superfluous (and are related to a different test altogether).  You only need to collect the slope estimates.  That might make the answer to your question a little more evident ;-).